# How do I protect only cells with text in using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I know how to protect a sheet using the following:-

```
Sub Protect()

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Locked = False
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:b10").Locked = True
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="erty", UserInterfaceOnly:=True


End Sub
```

I only want to protect cells that have text in. My problem is that the number of columns varies. How do I count the columns and only protect cells with text in them?

Comment: you can use `Worksheet.UsedRange` to capture all the cells from A1 to the bottom-rightmost used cell

Comment: @iamangeet What am I missing? When I use this code it still locks up all the cells to the furthest column to the right,ws1.Cells.Locked = False
    ws1.UsedRange.Locked = True
    ws1.Protect Password:="pass", UserInterfaceOnly:=True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would achieve what you are expecting:

```
Sub protectit()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with, amend as required
Dim c As Range
ws.Cells.Locked = False 'unlock all the cells in the given Sheet
For Each c In ws.UsedRange 'for each cell in UsedRange
    If c.Value <> "" Then c.Locked = True 'if cell is not empty then locked = True
Next
ws.protect Password:="erty", UserInterfaceOnly:=True 'protect the populated cells
End Sub
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can just check all the cells and lock them if there's text:

```
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell in Sheet1.UsedRange
    If Cell.Value <> "" Then Cell.Locked = True
Next Cell
```